# Google App Script UrlFetchApp with Bearer token but get bad request

Tags: google-apps-script, bad-request

I'm using VPN and trying to access data using `UrlFetchApp` in GAS.
Here is my code:

```js
const token = "eyJ0eXAiO...";

var params = {
  method:"GET",
  contentType:'application/json',
  headers:{Authorization:"Bearer "+token},
  muteHttpExceptions:true
};

function myFunction() {
  var url = 'http://192.168.2.22/api/v1/classes/information?page=1';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
}
```

The api along with the token works both in Postman and Python Request. However, when using the GAS script above (and connected with VPN), I keep receiving `Bad Request` error as the following screenshot:

[image]

I wonder what I am missing in my script?
Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The request is from Google server so your VPN does not matter. The possible reason is the endpoint has banned Google IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Postman and Python are likely running locally, GAS is running remotely, it can't connect to your local IP address (192.168.*.* is always local). You need to use a public IP address through dynamic DNS for example if you want it to connect to your local machine.